# How to fire event in Javascript (with KineticJs) upon spacebar or arrowkey keystroke

Tags: javascript, syntax, kineticjs

how does one fire an event in javascript upon space bar click or arrow key strike?  I am using kineticjs as my framework, although that may be irrelevant as this may be able to be done in regular javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS doesn't handle keyboard events and I don't think it will be one day as Kinetic is used as a HTML5 Canvas JavaScript framework.

But KineticJS is compatible with JQuery which can provide you what you need.

Here is an example :

```
 $(document).keydown(function(event){

        console.log("key index : " + event.which);

        if (event.which == 38) {          //UP                                                              
            console.log("Up");
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.which == 37) {   //LEFT                                                            
            console.log("Left");
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.which == 39) {   //RIGHT                                                            
            console.log("Right");
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.which == 40) {   //DOWN                                                            
            console.log("Right");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Xavier

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to look around a bit for a list of keystroke values that correspond to there "which" value (just saying which because that's what the code is saying).  Do you know if a list like this exists? I was unable to figure out that 38 means up, etc.

Comment: @hippofluff There are a few lists around, this article has one near the bottom and also talks about a lot of the complexities of keyboard input. http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Comment: You can easily retrieve these keys by logging them via the console. console.log("key index : " + event.which);

Comment: And @XavierHaennig that is definitely a good point and it will be implemented, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

KineticJS unfortunately doesn't handle keyboard events.  You can do it with vanilla javascript but it can be a bit tedious.  There are a few great libraries out there that can take care of it for you, I've been using [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/) to great effect.

Quick example:

```
KeyboardJS.on("ctrl + c", function() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    tempNode = selectedNode.clone();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I have to I will resort to using a library.  For the sake of coding knowledge is there a realistic way to do this in standard javascript? Or would I end up re-inventing the wheel.